# invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a new login page for staff and encountered an error

```
    mDB.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    String strSql1 = "SELECT * FROM Employee ";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql1, mDB);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == (string)rdr["eUserName"] &&
            txtPassword.Text == (string)rdr["ePassword"])
         {
            Session["sFlag"] = "T"; // sFlag = "T" means user has logged in
            Session["sFirstName"] = rdr["eFirstName"];
            Session["sLastName"] = rdr["eLastName"];
            Session["sUsername"] = rdr["eUserName"];
            btnLogout.Visible = true;
            btnLogin.Visible = false;
            mDB.Close();

        } //end of if
    } //end of while loop
 // userid and password not matched, hence login unsuccessful
    Session["sFlag"] = "F";
    Session["sName"] = "";
    Session["sUsername"] = "";
    lblMessage.Text = "Username and password does not match- please try again.  ";
    mDB.Close();
}
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnLogout.Visible = false;
    Session["sFlag"] = "L"; // L for logout
    Session["sFirstName"] = "";
    Session["sUsername"] = "";

}
```

it works fine for my other login page for customers. Help please? I'm very new to this. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: What's that `mDB.Close();` inside the loop going to do, do you think? (Perhaps you should add a `break;` on the line below it.)

Comment: The reader is closed once you've closed your connection inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You're closing the connection inside the reading loop (using `mDB.Close();`). That's not a good thing at all. To solve that, move the close call to be done after the end of the loop:

```
while (rdr.Read() == true)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text == (string)rdr["eUserName"] &&
        txtPassword.Text == (string)rdr["ePassword"])
    {
        Session["sFlag"] = "T"; // sFlag = "T" means user has logged in
        Session["sFirstName"] = rdr["eFirstName"];
        Session["sLastName"] = rdr["eLastName"];
        Session["sUsername"] = rdr["eUserName"];
        btnLogout.Visible = true;
        btnLogin.Visible = false;


    } //end of if
} //end of while loop
mDB.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the connection in the loop, so `rdr.Read()` will use a closed connection to check if there is a second record. That will fail.

Instead you should use the `using`-statement, which ensures that the connection gets closed even in case of an error:

```
using(var mDB = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    mDB.Open();
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee", mDB))
    using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (rdr.Read() == true)
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == (string)rdr["eUserName"] &&
                txtPassword.Text == (string)rdr["ePassword"])
             {
                Session["sFlag"] = "T"; // sFlag = "T" means user has logged in
                Session["sFirstName"] = rdr["eFirstName"];
                Session["sLastName"] = rdr["eLastName"];
                Session["sUsername"] = rdr["eUserName"];
                btnLogout.Visible = true;
                btnLogin.Visible = false;        
            } //end of if
        } //end of while loop
    }
}
```

**Side-Note**: you are selecting all records and filtering at the client. Instead you should `WHERE` to filter in the database:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE eUserName=@Username AND @ePassword=PassWord", mDB))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ePassword", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
    // ...
}
```